# How to configure proxy url in weblogic to connect destination from source via Proxy

Tags: https, server, proxy, weblogic12c

I have deployed an application in weblogic managed server which internally connects to cloud network, since this application where I deployed is a secured network so it should connect via proxy and hence I need to configure the proxy url settings in weblogic, I added below settings in server start option in weblogic managed server however application is getting fail to start.

For Example:-

```
Source Ip:- SourceIp 
Destination Ip:- DestIP(which is configured in application properties file) 
Proxy Url :- ProxyIp 
Proxy port :- 8080
```

Configuration done in managed server as per below.

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost= ProxyIp-Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxyHost=ProxyIp-Dhttps.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=SourceIp
```

Note:- If I deploy the application in non secured network where I do not need to configure any proxy works fine and application gets started. I am expecting post proxy configuration in web logic, my app should up and running.However I get below error:

> DestIp failed: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)

Comment: Can you clarify why you should need a proxy for secured outbound connections and not for non secured outbound connections ?

Comment: Hi, I need proxy to connect to Destination from Source because destination is in public cloud and to connect to public network, source should have access of internet, since source must go through proxy to connect to internet, that is the reason.

Comment: so, you go through the proxy for http and https traffic, no ?